# Easier way of turning duplicates into blank entries in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, `df`:

```
ID <- c('ID1','ID1','ID2','ID3','ID3','ID3','ID4')
hr <- c(10,20,10,15,20,10,15)
DD <- c('DD1','DD2','DD3','DD4','DD5','DD6','DD7')
ddhr <- c(15,20,30,20,10,15,10)
df <- data.frame(ID,hr,DD,ddhr)
df
   ID hr  DD ddhr
1 ID1 10 DD1   15
2 ID1 20 DD2   20
3 ID2 10 DD3   30
4 ID3 15 DD4   20
5 ID3 20 DD5   10
6 ID3 10 DD6   15
7 ID4 15 DD7   10
```

This data frame is ordered by `df$ID`.

I want to alter this data frame, so that every time a duplicate `df$ID` entry occurs, that duplicate entry and the corresponding `df$hr` entry are converted to blank entries (`""`).

The ideal resulting dataframe would look like this:

```
   ID hr  DD ddhr
1 ID1 10 DD1   15
2        DD2   20
3 ID2 10 DD3   30
4 ID3 15 DD4   20
5        DD5   10
6        DD6   15
7 ID4 15 DD7   10
```

What is the best way of doing this?  I have tried:

```
df$ID=as.character(df$ID)
df$ID=ifelse(!duplicated(df$ID)==FALSE,"",df$ID)
df$hr=ifelse(df$ID=="","",df$hr)
```

But this seems a bit lengthy, particularly if I have more than one additional column I want to blank out (other than hr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following. Note that the character columns (`ID` and `DD`) are of type character and not factor.

```
df[duplicated(df$ID),1:2] <- ""
df
   ID hr  DD ddhr
1 ID1 10 DD1   15
2        DD2   20
3 ID2 10 DD3   30
4 ID3 15 DD4   20
5        DD5   10
6        DD6   15
7 ID4 15 DD7   10
```